# Reactnavigation params error "undefined is not an object evaluating route.params"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, routeparams

I get the error mentioned in the title and solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855691/typeerror-route-is-undefined-and-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-route) do not seem to work.

The user starts on screen 1 and then goes to several other screens before ending up on screen 1 again. When the user goes to screen 1 (again) I want to pass some params (and somehow use thos params to force a re-render of that component). This is my code:

**Screen 1**

```
function Screen 1(props, { route, navigation }) {
...
const { itemId } = route.params;
  console.log(itemId);
```

**Screen X** (the last screen the user visits before going back to screen 1)

```
      onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate("Screen_1", { itemId: Doe });
          }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix destructuring of props and the props object at the same time, hence the statement

```js
function Screen1(props, { route, navigation }) { ... }
```

is not valid.

You need to either destructure everything you need from `props` or use the props object.

```js
function Screen1({ route, navigation }) {

    const { itemId } = route.params
}
```

or

```js
function Screen1(props) {
    const { itemId } = props.route.params
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it still won't work. Could be the problem that when I first enter screen 1 there is no params to be passed yet?  I pass it only when I get to Screen 1 "again" at a later stage?

Comment: So I just added some initial params `  initialParams={{ itemId: 42 }}` in my stack navigation and it works :-) Together with your answer this must have done the trick. Thank you :-)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you do not pass the params during navigation, they won’t be accessible. Using initialParams is the way to go! I’m glad it worked out :)